# Local Notification rescheduling after reboot iOS

Tags: ios, database, xamarin, reboot, localnotification

My goal is to reschedule my local notifications after reboot because they get lost after it. So I need some service that will listen for device swithing off and than will reschedule all local notifications. I found some material about Broadcast Receiver in Android, but I can't find any such information about iOS.

I store my notifications in database. So when device is rebooted - I need to read all my active notification that hasn't been fired and reschedule them. Is there any way to do it?

Also I'm using Xamarin but it seems like it's not useful anyway in that case.

Any pointing to the right way will be grateful.

Comment: iOS doesn't have any such thing.  No such thing as a service, no such thing as a broadcast receiver, no such thing as running after boot, no such thing as registering for device reboot notifications. Neither are there any equivalents. You simply can't do this sort of thing on iOS.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to anyone who ever wondered about such question.
iOS do have his own notification system that stores notifications in memory. And when device reboots it just invokes all active notifications as if there was no reboot at all. 
So for sure there is no need to implement anything on this problem.